# ID3D11Texture2D to ID2D1Bitmap, is it possible?

Tags: directx, direct3d, directx-11, direct2d, dxgi

I am working on a extension to a game which only opens a HDC for addon developers to draw on.

However, I have exhausted GDI+/Direct2D drawing possibilities that is fast enough for what I want to accomplish - image effects(Additive, Blend, Multiply Blend etc).

I am well aware that Direct2D offers a effects toolkit however, that requires a platform update (for Windows 7) and that is not ideal at all.

Hence I am left with only Direct3D. MSDN/Google Search offers lots of ways to do D2D -> D3D, but ZERO shows how to do D3D -> D2D. I know there is a method to convert D3D - > D2D and that is to map and copy pixel data, but that is highly inefficient as (if I am right) it transfers from GPU VRAM -> CPU/RAM -> GPU VRAM. I will probably only use that as a last alternative....

Alternatively, it might also work if someone has any idea on how to grab a HDC from RenderTarget in D3D11 so that I can BitBlt.

I would be grateful if anyone can help with this.

Comment: Not very clear of your question, what do you want?

Comment: Capture Backbuffer for D3D as ID3D11Texture2D and convert to ID2D1Bitmap to send to D2D, how to do that if possible. Hope its clear enough.

Comment: You should describe something about the business logic, do you want to do a realtime sync between D3D and D2D or not?

Comment: Yes, since I used D3D for image processing, I need it to appear almost instantly. (but it need not be updated every frame, only when the image changes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok I figured it out. Probably not the most efficient, but does the job.
No memcpy,bitblt (although inside the CreateBitmap from memory might have those functions inside). Avoids all the DXGI version crap too.

```cpp
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC td;
m_backBufferTexture->GetDesc(&td);
td.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
td.BindFlags = 0;
td.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;

m_pDevice->CreateTexture2D( &td, NULL, &(m_pNewTexture) );
m_pContext->CopyResource(m_pNewTexture, m_backBufferTexture);
m_pNewTexture->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGISurface), (void**)&m_NewTextDXGI);

DXGI_MAPPED_RECT bitmap2Dmap;
m_NewTextDXGI->Map(&bitmap2Dmap,DXGI_MAP_READ);

D2D1_PIXEL_FORMAT desc2d;
D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES bmpprops;

desc2d.format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
desc2d.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE; // Adapt to your needs.      

bmpprops.dpiX = 96.0f;
bmpprops.dpiY = 96.0f;
bmpprops.pixelFormat = desc2d;


D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(
dim.x,
dim.y
); // Adapt to your own size.

pRT->CreateBitmap(size,(void*)bitmap2Dmap.pBits,bitmap2Dmap.Pitch,bmpprops,&m_pD2DBitmap);
m_NewTextDXGI->Unmap();
```

Comment: hi, i was also working on a similar situation, can you please share the full code.

Comment: None of this helps anyone else looking for an answer. You throw in code, thinking everyone could guess where and how certain objects are initialized before being used. For instance, what is `pRT`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Surface Sharing Between Windows Graphics APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee913554.aspx)

you can focus on section **Direct3D 10.1 Device Sharing with Direct2D**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateSharedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create `ID2D1Bitmap` that shares surface with the `IDXGISurface`.

Quote: ... you can pass an `IDXGISurface` surface to the `CreateSharedBitmap` method to share video memory with Direct3D and manipulate Direct3D content as an ID2D1Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
bool ConvertID3D11Texture2DToID2D1Bitmap(ID3D11DeviceContext* ctx, 
                                         ID3D11Texture2D* texture, 
                                         ID2D1Bitmap* bitmap)
{
      ComPtr<IDXGISurface> dxgiSurface;
      HRESULT hr = bitmap->GetSurface(&dxgiSurface);
      if (hr != S_OK)
           return false;
      ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> d3dResource;
      hr = dxgiSurface.As(&d3dResource);
      if (hr != S_OK)
           return false;
      ctx->CopyResource(d3dResource.Get(), texture);
}
```

All the job is done on GPU. You should ensure the texture and the bitmap have same format.