# CLSID_D2D1ChromaKey issues

Tags: c++, gpu, directx-11, direct2d, direct3d11

I try to use DirectX ChromaKey effect, but my function stucks on some step.
What I do:

1. Create ID2D1Factory1
2. Create ID3D11Device and ID3D11DeviceContext
3. Obtain DXGIResource from received texture
4. Obtain shared handle from DXGIResource
5. Open DXGIResource as new ID3D11Texture2D using ID3D11Device
6. Obtain D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC of new ID3D11Texture2D
7. Create new ID3D11Texture2D using input ID3D11Texture2D and D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC
8. Copy resource from obtained ID3D11Texture2D to created ID3D11Texture2D
9. Obtain IDXGISurface from created ID3D11Texture2D
10. Define D2D1_SIZE_U, D2D1_PIXEL_FORMAT, D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES
11. Obtain desktop DPI from ID2D1Factory1
12. Create D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES using obtained DPI
13. Create ID2D1RenderTarget using ID2D1Factory1, IDXGISurface and D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES
14. Create shared ID2D1Bitmap using ID2D1RenderTarget, IDXGISurface and D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES
15. Obtain IDXGIDevice using ID3D11Device
16. Create ID2D1Device using ID2D1Factory1 and IDXGIDevice
17. Obtain ID2D1DeviceContext using ID2D1Device
18. Create ChromaKey ID2D1Effect using ID2D1DeviceContext
19. Define D2D1_VECTOR_3F basing on ChromaKey background
20. Set parameters and D2D1_VECTOR_3F of ID2D1Effect
21. Drow over ID2D1Bitmap using ID2D1DeviceContext, and ID2D1Effect
22. Return new ID3D11Texture2D bound to ID2D1Bitmap

Here is a code.

**Defines:**

```
#define SIZEOF_ARRAY(arr)   (sizeof(arr)/sizeof((arr)[0]))
#define RET_HR(_f) hr = _f; if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;
#define RET_HR_NULL( _f, _obj ) hr = _f; if (FAILED(hr) || !_obj) return FAILED(hr) ? hr : S_FALSE;
```

**Device creation:**

```
inline CComPtr<ID3D11Device> DX11_CreateDevice(IDXGIAdapter* _pAdapter, ID3D11DeviceContext** _ppD2D1DeviceContext = NULL)
{
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC dxgiDesc = {};
    CComQIPtr<IDXGIAdapter> qpDXGIAdapter(_pAdapter);
    if (qpDXGIAdapter)
        qpDXGIAdapter->GetDesc(&dxgiDesc);

    CComPtr<ID3D11Device> cpD3D11Device;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL d3dFeature = (D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL)0;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL arrD3DFeatures[] = {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1 };

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    RET_HR(D3D11CreateDevice(
        qpDXGIAdapter, 
        qpDXGIAdapter ? D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN : D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, 
        nullptr, 
        D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, 
        arrD3DFeatures, 
        SIZEOF_ARRAY(arrD3DFeatures), 
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, 
        &cpD3D11Device, 
        &d3dFeature, 
        _ppD2D1DeviceContext
    ));

    CComQIPtr<ID3D10Multithread> qpMTProtect(cpD3D11Device);
    ATLASSERT(qpMTProtect);
    if (qpMTProtect)
        qpMTProtect->SetMultithreadProtected(TRUE);

    return cpD3D11Device;
}
```

**ChromaKey code:**

```
HRESULT DXV_ChromaKey(ID3D11Texture2D* _pTexIn, ID3D11Texture2D** _pTexOut)
{
    // -----------------
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    CComPtr<ID2D1Factory1> cpD2DFactory;
    RET_HR_NULL(D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &cpD2DFactory), cpD2DFactory);

    // Create the DX11 API device object, and get a corresponding context.
    CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> cpD3D11DeviceContext;

    CComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> cpNVidiaAdpt = DXGI_AdapterByType(eGPU_NVidia);
    CComPtr<ID3D11Device> cpD3D11Device = DX11_CreateDevice(cpNVidiaAdpt, &cpD3D11DeviceContext);

    CComPtr<IDXGIResource> cpDXGIResource;
    RET_HR_NULL(_pTexIn->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&cpDXGIResource), cpDXGIResource);

    HANDLE sharedHandle;
    cpDXGIResource->GetSharedHandle(&sharedHandle);

    CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> cpTexIn;
    cpD3D11Device->OpenSharedResource(sharedHandle, __uuidof(ID3D11Resource), (void**)(&cpTexIn));

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC td;
    cpTexIn->GetDesc(&td);
    td.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    td.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;

    CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> cpNewTexture;
    RET_HR_NULL(cpD3D11Device->CreateTexture2D(&td, NULL, &cpNewTexture), cpNewTexture);

    cpD3D11DeviceContext->CopyResource(cpNewTexture, cpTexIn);

    CComPtr<IDXGISurface> cpDXGISurface;
    RET_HR_NULL(cpNewTexture->QueryInterface(&cpDXGISurface), cpDXGISurface);

    // -----------------

    D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(200, 200); // Adapt to your own size.

    D2D1_PIXEL_FORMAT desc2d;
    desc2d.format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    desc2d.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE; // Adapt to your needs.      

    D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES bmpprops;
    bmpprops.dpiX = 96.0f;
    bmpprops.dpiY = 96.0f;
    bmpprops.pixelFormat = desc2d;

    FLOAT dpiX;
    FLOAT dpiY;
    cpD2DFactory->GetDesktopDpi(&dpiX, &dpiY);

    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES d2d1RenderTargetProperties =
        D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
            D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
            D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED),
            dpiX,
            dpiY
        );

    CComPtr<ID2D1RenderTarget> cpRenderTarget;
    RET_HR_NULL(cpD2DFactory->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(
        cpDXGISurface,
        &d2d1RenderTargetProperties,
        &cpRenderTarget),
        cpRenderTarget);

    // -----------------

    CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> cpBitmap;
    cpRenderTarget->CreateSharedBitmap(__uuidof(IDXGISurface), cpDXGISurface, &bmpprops, &cpBitmap);

    // -----------------

    CComPtr<IDXGIDevice> cpDXGIDevice;
    // Obtain the underlying DXGI device of the Direct3D11 device.
    RET_HR_NULL(cpD3D11Device->QueryInterface(&cpDXGIDevice), cpDXGIDevice);

    CComPtr<ID2D1Device> cpD2D1Device;
    // Obtain the Direct2D device for 2-D rendering.
    RET_HR_NULL(cpD2DFactory->CreateDevice(cpDXGIDevice, &cpD2D1Device), cpD2D1Device);

    CComPtr<ID2D1DeviceContext> cpD2DContext;
    // Get Direct2D device's corresponding device context object.
    RET_HR_NULL(cpD2D1Device->CreateDeviceContext(
        D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE,
        &cpD2DContext
    ), cpD2DContext);

    CComPtr<ID2D1Effect> chromakeyEffect;
    RET_HR_NULL(cpD2DContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1ChromaKey, &chromakeyEffect), chromakeyEffect);

    D2D1_VECTOR_3F Vector3F;
    Vector3F.x = .32f;
    Vector3F.y = .99f;
    Vector3F.z = .48f;

    int nSize = sizeof(Vector3F);
    BYTE* pData = (BYTE*)&Vector3F;

    chromakeyEffect->SetInput(0, cpBitmap);
    RET_HR(chromakeyEffect->SetValue(D2D1_CHROMAKEY_PROP_COLOR, pData, nSize));
    RET_HR(chromakeyEffect->SetValue(D2D1_CHROMAKEY_PROP_TOLERANCE, 0.2f));
    RET_HR(chromakeyEffect->SetValue(D2D1_CHROMAKEY_PROP_INVERT_ALPHA, false));
    RET_HR(chromakeyEffect->SetValue(D2D1_CHROMAKEY_PROP_FEATHER, false));

    cpD2DContext->BeginDraw();
    cpD2DContext->DrawImage(chromakeyEffect);
    RET_HR(cpD2DContext->EndDraw());

    return cpNewTexture->QueryInterface(_pTexOut);
    // -----------------
}
```

**Entry point:**

```
TEST_METHOD(UT_DXV_ChromaKey)
{
    MTimeout timeOut(__FUNCTION__);
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    DX11Texture::TPtr apTexturePicOrg;
    DX_TextureLoadFromFile(cbsChromaCat, &apTexturePicOrg);
    Assert::IsTrue(apTexturePicOrg);

    CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> cpD3D11Texture;
    hr = m_arrVidProcessor[0]->DXV_ChromaKey(apTexturePicOrg, &cpD3D11Texture);

    CComPtr<IMFFrame> cpMFFrameCnv;
    MCreator::MFFrameCreateFromTexture(NULL, cpD3D11Texture, 0, NULL, &cpMFFrameCnv, NULL);
    cpMFFrameCnv->MFVideoSaveToFile(L"C:\\temp\\Kosh.bmp");
}
```

The input picture:
[image]

Now, I'm stucking on 13th step:

> 13. Create ID2D1RenderTarget using ID2D1Factory1, IDXGISurface and D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES

```
RET_HR_NULL(cpD2DFactory->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(
        cpDXGISurface,
        &d2d1RenderTargetProperties,
        &cpRenderTarget),
        cpRenderTarget);
```

Despite `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` I get just follow error as `HRESULT` of `CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget`:

> E_INVALIDARG One or more arguments are invalid.

Here is content of `td` and description of `cpDXGISurface`:

```
td  {Width=0x00000354 Height=0x000001e0 MipLevels=0x00000001 ...}   D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC
    Width   0x00000354  unsigned int
    Height  0x000001e0  unsigned int
    MipLevels   0x00000001  unsigned int
    ArraySize   0x00000001  unsigned int
    Format  DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM (0x00000057) DXGI_FORMAT
    SampleDesc  {Count=0x00000001 Quality=0x00000000 }  DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC
    Usage   D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT (0x00000000)    D3D11_USAGE
    BindFlags   0x00000008  unsigned int
    CPUAccessFlags  0x00020000  unsigned int
    MiscFlags   0x00000002  unsigned int

sd  {Width=0x00000354 Height=0x000001e0 Format=DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM (0x00000057) ...} DXGI_SURFACE_DESC
    Width   0x00000354  unsigned int
    Height  0x000001e0  unsigned int
    Format  DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM (0x00000057) DXGI_FORMAT
    SampleDesc  {Count=0x00000001 Quality=0x00000000 }  DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC
```

Comment: `1` use [Direct3D debug layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps) to get extended error information in your debug output `2` having `Map` failure you are interested in re-checking texture caps, the texture might be (and I guess it's the issue!) not mappable; you might need an additionalstep of copying this texture into staging texture first

Comment: I updated the question ) Thanx for advise!

Comment: Your original code was closer to what you need. You can't have staging there where you have it. You should revert it and then add copying to staging right before you `Map` later, so that you map staging texture instead.

Comment: But, I have to copy to staging rigth before Map in all my variants. I will upload now new version with last changes and error.

Comment: Please see updated version )

Comment: Here I asked related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60706884/a-d3d11-usage-staging-resource-cannot-be-shared-via-d3d11-resource-misc-shared-k

Comment: The error in "updated" section suggests you don't have `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ` on the texture you are mapping. It's hard to follow the changes.

Comment: But I have D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ there... (See update)

Comment: I opened separeted question for it, as in previous time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708675/idxgisurfacemap-this-object-was-not-created-with-cpuaccess-flags-that-allow-c

Comment: OK, I seem to understand now... I thought you're mapping output texture (for reading!) but you are mapping input texture. Why? In my defense the execution flow is hard to read from the snippets. I am also confused why you are using `IDXGISurface::Map` at all? You don't seem to need it. Perhaps you should explain yourself what you are trying to achieve. You already have a texture you use as input. Is it compatible with D2D? If yes, just use it first further. In it's not, create a compatible and copy input texture there. You don't need `Map` for either of the two.

Comment: Even if you do want `Map`, why `IDXGISurface::Map`? You have `ID3D11DeviceContext::Map` which is appropriate for accessing texture data with textures that assume this. I would say you are not supposed to do `IDXGISurface::Map` at all. Then if `Map` for reading output is intended you end drawing, then you either map the texture or copy it to mappable and map that second one.

Comment: The only type acceptable by SetInput of ID2D1Effect is ID2D1Image. And I can not convert ID3D11Texture2D to ID2D1Image in a simple way... I used manual at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383209/id3d11texture2d-to-id2d1bitmap-is-it-possible . Now, I will try ID3D11DeviceContext::Map() but it weem much more difficult than IDXGISurface::Map()

Comment: You don't need `Map` anyway. Even though it is possible, this path with `Map` and `CreateBitmap` is an apparent performance hit. You could and should use other API instead. [By using `CreateSharedBitmap` to create an `ID2D1Bitmap` from an `IDXGISurface`, you can write a Direct3D scene to a bitmap and render it with Direct2D.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-direct3d-interoperation-overview).

Comment: OK, I updated there the code. Now I have E_INVALIDARG on CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget