# IDXGISurface::Map: This object was not created with CPUAccess flags that allow CPU access

Tags: c++, directx, direct2

I try to create new `ID3D11Texture2D` for map it to `DXGI_MAPPED_RECT` further.
I receive some `ID3D11Texture2D` that I have no power on (can not change way of creation of).

Here is the part of the code:

```
CComPtr<IDXGIResource> cpDXGIResource;
RET_HR_NULL(_pTexIn->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&cpDXGIResource), cpDXGIResource);

HANDLE sharedHandle;
cpDXGIResource->GetSharedHandle(&sharedHandle);

CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> cpTexIn;
cpD3D11Device->OpenSharedResource(sharedHandle, __uuidof(ID3D11Resource), (void**)(&cpTexIn));

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC td;
cpTexIn->GetDesc(&td);
td.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
td.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
td.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;

CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> cpNewTexture;
RET_HR_NULL(cpD3D11Device->CreateTexture2D(&td, NULL, &cpNewTexture), cpNewTexture);

cpD3D11DeviceContext->CopyResource(cpNewTexture, cpTexIn);

CComPtr<IDXGISurface> cpDXGISurface;
RET_HR_NULL(cpNewTexture->QueryInterface(&cpDXGISurface), cpDXGISurface);

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC ntd;
cpNewTexture->GetDesc(&ntd);

DXGI_SURFACE_DESC sd;
cpDXGISurface->GetDesc(&sd);

DXGI_MAPPED_RECT bitmap2Dmap;
RET_HR(cpDXGISurface->Map(&bitmap2Dmap, DXGI_MAP_READ));
```

`_pTexIn` is an input ID3D11Texture2D.
I get the error below while `Map()`:

```
RET_HR(cpDXGISurface->Map(&bitmap2Dmap, DXGI_MAP_READ));
```

> DXGI ERROR: IDXGISurface::Map: This object was not created with
>   CPUAccess flags that allow CPU access. [ MISCELLANEOUS ERROR #42: ]
>   Exception thrown at 0x76734192 in testhost.x86.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0716E134. The thread 0x26bc
>   has exited with code 0 (0x0).

**BUT!**, actually I have `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ` set on the `cpNewTexture`.
See output of ntd and sd below:

Here is content of `ntd` and `sd`:

```
ntd {Width=0x00000354 Height=0x000001e0 MipLevels=0x00000001 ...}   D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC
    Width   0x00000354  unsigned int
    Height  0x000001e0  unsigned int
    MipLevels   0x00000001  unsigned int
    ArraySize   0x00000001  unsigned int
    Format  DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM (0x00000057) DXGI_FORMAT
    SampleDesc  {Count=0x00000001 Quality=0x00000000 }  DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC
    Usage   D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT (0x00000000)    D3D11_USAGE
    BindFlags   0x00000008  unsigned int
    CPUAccessFlags  0x00020000  unsigned int
    MiscFlags   0x00000002  unsigned int


sd  {Width=0x00000354 Height=0x000001e0 Format=DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM (0x00000057) ...} DXGI_SURFACE_DESC
    Width   0x00000354  unsigned int
    Height  0x000001e0  unsigned int
    Format  DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM (0x00000057) DXGI_FORMAT
    SampleDesc  {Count=0x00000001 Quality=0x00000000 }  DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, in the main [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621606/clsid-d2d1chromakey-issues-such-as-e-invalidarg-on-idxgisurfacemap) [Roma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/868014/roman-r) gave follow explonation:

> OK, I seem to understand now... I thought you're mapping output
>   texture (for reading!) but you are mapping input texture. Why? In my
>   defense the execution flow is hard to read from the snippets. I am
>   also confused why you are using `IDXGISurface::Map()` at all? You don't
>   seem to need it. Perhaps you should explain yourself what you are
>   trying to achieve. You already have a texture you use as input. Is it
>   compatible with `D2D`? If yes, just use it first further. In it's not,
>   create a compatible and copy input texture there. You don't need Map
>   for either of the two.
>
> Even if you do want Map, why `IDXGISurface::Map()`?
>   You have `ID3D11DeviceContext::Map()` which is appropriate for accessing
>   texture data with textures that assume this. I would say you are not
>   supposed to do `IDXGISurface::Map()` at all. Then if `Map()` for reading
>   output is intended you end drawing, then you either map the texture or
>   copy it to mappable and map that second one.

**After all**

> You don't need `Map()` anyway. Even though it is possible, this path with
>   `Map()` and `CreateBitmap()` is an apparent performance hit. [You could and
>   should use other API instead. By using CreateSharedBitmap to create an
>   ID2D1Bitmap from an IDXGISurface, you can write a Direct3D scene to a
>   bitmap and render it with Direct2D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-direct3d-interoperation-overview).